# Why does the polarization vector P depend on the net electric field and not the original one?

Tags: electric-fields, polarization, dielectric

**P**= χε<sub>0</sub>**E**,

where **E**  is the net electric field from the effects of both free and bound charges.

But **E**=(σ<sub>free</sub>-**P**)/ε<sub>0</sub>

So **E** itself depends on P.

My concern is, isn't this circular? How can the polarization density depend on a field that itself depends on it? Shouldn't it depend on the original field between the conducting plates, **E<sub>0</sub>**, given by

**E<sub>0</sub>**=σ<sub>free</sub>/ε<sub>0</sub>   ?

Comment: First of all, it is in general $P^j = \chi^j_k E^k$. The electric field is *not* derived in terms of the polarisation vector: it is what it is and can be calculated using any method you want (solving the Maxwell’s equations). If the polarisation is already given (for some reasons), than in particular cases (since the above relation holds) you can invert it and determine the electric field as viceversa.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco Could you elaborate on "it is what it is"?

Comment: Within the medium, the electric field in any point and time depends on the distribution of charges and currents and can (in principle) be calculated. Once so, the polarisation vector can be expressed in terms of such internal electric field; summing over all the contributions one obtains the general macroscopic expression stated above.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco Aahh, now I see. Danke schoen!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These kinds of problems are called self consistent. You say,

> How can the polarization density depend on a field that itself depends on it? Shouldn't it depend on the original field between the conducting plates, $E_0$?

Once the original field $E_0$ has polarized the dielectric, the bound surface charges create their own fields. Now ask yourself, what is to stop this new field from also affecting the polarization of the dielectric? The dielectric does not *know* that its own surface bound charges have created another field. So the polarization must depend on the *net* field, including that of the dielectric.